# Gatsbyjs rendering page twice when accessing directly with url

Tags: javascript, gatsby

I have a website built with gastbyJs v4.12.1
I have a product search page which is built using a page template passing the products in the page context.
When navigating from menu the pages work fine, but when I access the page directly from url, the component in the page looks like rendered twice, first without the products, then with the products appended.
I have a test page here: https://brit-tr.com/urunler

```
import * as React from 'react'
import { useState } from 'react'
import { Divider, Grid, Pagination, sliderClasses, Typography } from '@mui/material'
import { makeStyles } from '@mui/styles'
import FilterComponent from './sidebar-filter'
import ProductCard from './product-card'
import Accordion from '@mui/material/Accordion';
import AccordionSummary from '@mui/material/AccordionSummary';
import AccordionDetails from '@mui/material/AccordionDetails';
import ExpandMoreIcon from '@mui/icons-material/ExpandMore';



const getFilterModel = (products) => {
    let brands = []
    let types = []
    let ages = []
    let breeds = []
    let features = []
    let petTypes=[]
    products.forEach(product => {
        brands.push(product?.brand?.brandName)
        product.type?.forEach(type => types.push(type))
        product.ageGroup?.forEach(age => ages.push(age))
        product.breeds?.forEach(breed => breeds.push(breed))
        product.special_care?.forEach(feature => features.push(feature.name))
        petTypes.push(product.for_cats?'cats':'dogs')
    });
    
    return { brands: [...new Set(brands)], types: [...new Set(types)], ages: [...new Set(ages)].sort(), breeds: [...new Set(breeds)], features: [...new Set(features)], petTypes: [...new Set(petTypes)] };
}

const filterPrdcts = (products, filter) => {

    let petTypes = []
    if (filter?.petTypes) {
        if (filter.petTypes.includes('cats')) {
            petTypes.push(true)
        }
        if (filter.petTypes.includes('dogs')) {
            petTypes.push(false)
        }

    }
    const filteredByBrands = (filter.brands.length > 0) ? products.filter(product => filter.brands.includes(product.brand.brandName)) : [...products]
    const filteredByTypes = (filter.types.length > 0) ? filteredByBrands.filter(product => filter.types.some(r => product.type.includes(r))) : [...filteredByBrands]
    const filteredByPetTypes = (petTypes.length > 0) ? filteredByTypes.filter(product => petTypes.includes(product.for_cats)) : [...filteredByTypes]
    const filteredByBreeds = (filter.breeds.length > 0) ? filteredByPetTypes.filter(product => filter.breeds.some(r => product.breeds?.includes(r))) :[...filteredByPetTypes]
    const filteredByAgeGroups = (filter.ages.length > 0) ? filteredByBreeds.filter(product => filter.ages.some(r => product.ageGroup.includes(r))) : [...filteredByBreeds]
    
    const filteredByFeature = (filter.features?.length > 0) ? filteredByAgeGroups.filter(product => filter.features.some(r => (product.special_care?.filter(feature => (feature.name === r)).length > 0))) : [...filteredByAgeGroups]

    return (filteredByFeature)
}

const useStyles = makeStyles(theme => ({
    wrapper: {
        display: 'flex',
        flexDirection: 'row',

    },
    productListWrapper: {
        display: 'flex',
        flexWrap: 'wrap',
        alignItems: 'center',
        gap: '2rem'
    },
    hiddenOnMobile: {
        [theme.breakpoints.down('md')]: {
            display: 'none'
        }
    },
    hiddenOnDesktop: {
        [theme.breakpoints.up('md')]: {
            display: 'none'
        }
    }
}))


const ProductList = ({ products, checked, handleChange, flipPage}) => {

    const [filteredProducts, setFilteredProducts] = useState(products)
    const classes = useStyles()
    const filterModel = getFilterModel(products)
    const itemsPerPage = 9

    React.useEffect(() => {
        const filtered = filterPrdcts(products, checked)
        setFilteredProducts(filtered)
    }, [checked, products])

    React.useEffect(()=> {
        return () => console.log('unmounting Productlist')
    },[])
  

    return (
        <Grid className={classes.wrapper} container >
            <Grid item xs={3} sx={{ paddingTop: '10px' }} className={classes.hiddenOnMobile}>
                <FilterComponent options={filterModel} handleChange={handleChange} checked={checked} />
            </Grid>
            <Grid item xs={12} className={classes.hiddenOnDesktop}>
                <FilterAccordion options={filterModel} handleChange={handleChange} checked={checked} />
            </Grid>
            <Grid item xs={12} md={9} sx={{ paddingTop: '10px' }}>
                <div className={classes.productListWrapper}>
                    {filteredProducts?.slice((checked.page-1)*itemsPerPage,checked.page*itemsPerPage).map((product, index) => {
                        return (
                            <React.Fragment key={index}>
                                <ProductCard product={product} />
                                <Divider variant="fullWidth" className={classes.hiddenOnDesktop} sx={{width:'100%'}}/>
                            </React.Fragment>
                        )
                    })}
                </div>
                <Grid><Pagination count={(filteredProducts.length-filteredProducts.length%itemsPerPage)/itemsPerPage+1} onChange={flipPage} page={parseInt(checked.page)}/></Grid>
            </Grid>
            
        </Grid>
    )
}

const FilterAccordion = ({ options, handleChange, checked }) => {
    return (
        <Accordion >
            <AccordionSummary
                expandIcon={<ExpandMoreIcon />}
                aria-controls="panel1a-content"
                id="panel1a-header"
            >
                <Typography>Ürün Filtrele</Typography>
            </AccordionSummary>
            <AccordionDetails>
                <FilterComponent options={options} handleChange={handleChange} checked={checked} />
            </AccordionDetails>
        </Accordion>
    )
}




export default ProductList
```

Appreciate the help.

Comment: To be able to help you better, it is useful to provide some code, the relevant bits, on how you do your render and/or data fetching, otherwise it will be difficult to troubleshoot which part is wrong.

Comment: @benomatis thnk you for your effort. I think it is a hydration issue. Because the part that it appends on direct url access is the mobile version which should be hidden depending on the screen size. It works ok on gatsby develop mode, but not on production build. Do you have any idea how to solve this problem?

Comment: Again, without actual code there isn't really much anyone can give you other than trying to shoot in the dark, and just list things, but many of not all of those would be unnecessary or futile... So again, my recommendation is to share your code, and you'll have (much more useful) answers.

Comment: @benomatis I have edited my answer and pasted my code above. Thanks

Comment: Sorry, difficult for me to pinpoint without having all the code, but it will have to be the default values loaded by whatever influences your styling, it appears to render with some default values, and the custom ones you set in the file you have shown only kick in upon interaction with the app. You will have to figure out what those are and make sure they are set to  your desired values on first load. Specifically the elements you added the `hiddenOnDesktop` class to appear to be showing where they should not, and `item`s get an `overflow:hidden` at first load for some reason - figure out why

Comment: It seems that the mediaquery does not run on direct access to url.

Comment: Maybe the way you have set it up, but strictly speaking CSS media queries should take effect if included and loaded properly…

Answer (score 0):

it looks like it's a problem related to fetching the right data to render. It works fine when you navigate from page to page because it can prefetch the necessary data but not when accessing it directly from URL.
You can try using "useEffect" hook in your screen and let me know if it worked.

Comment: I think it is a hydration issue. Because the part that it appends on direct url access is the mobile version which should be hidden depending on the screen size. It works ok on gatsby develop mode, but not on production build. Do you have any idea how to solve this problem?

Comment: Maybe try to inspect the rendered HTML code to see if the necessary data attributes are present or if there are any JavaScript errors in the browser that could prevent the hydration process from working.

Comment: Also, try using css media queries to control the display of the mobile version based on the screen size rather than appending it to the URL. This will diplay the right version without relying on URL manipulation.